# xsim and "conditional" printing

Tags: conditionals, xsim

I'd like to know if the following is possible with the `xsim` package:

- Could the space created by commands like `\blank[width=4.8\linewidth,linespread=1.5]{}` (as given in the manual) **not** be printed if `solution/print` is set to `true`?
- Could a part of the document that is not a question be printed only if a particular tag is selected?

In other words, I'd like to achieve the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
solution/print = true,
tags = A
}

\begin{document}

% This part would be printed only if the tag A was selected.    
\somecommand{Instruction for A} 

\begin{exercise}[tags={A, B}]
    Tell me your mood
% Those lines would *not* be printed if solution/print is set to true.
\blank[width=4.8\linewidth,linespread=1.5]{} 
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

I've read the documentation but can't figure out whenever this is possible or not.

Comment: Do you mean *just using the user-interface of this package*? A page reference would be appreciated - the manual is 71 pages.

Comment: It would be nice to have this feature provided by the package, indeed, but I don't think this is the case. Section 11 is about "Printing Solutions", but doesn't say anything about triggering other commands with the `print` toggles. The same goes for tags, exposed in 7.4. The section 13.3. "Commands for Usage in Template Definitions" is rich in additional commands , but I don't see any command being able to trigger something outside a solution or question environment.

Comment: @Clément a lot of the kind of commands you are looking for are described in the section about creating exercise templates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no user command which checks if a tag has been set but it is easy to add one. I'll add something to the next release.

If you want to check if solutions are printed then use `\IfSolutionPrintTF` or one of its cousins:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  solution/print = true,
  tags = A
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% v0.11 will contain some command like this:
\NewDocumentCommand \IfTagSetTF {m+m+m}
  { \seq_if_in:NnTF \l__xsim_chosen_tags_tags_seq {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\NewDocumentCommand \IfTagSetT {m+m}
  { \IfTagSetTF {#1} {#2} {} }
\NewDocumentCommand \IfTagSetF {m+m}
  { \IfTagSetTF {#1} {} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\IfTagSetT{A}{Instruction for A} 

\begin{exercise}[tags={A, B}]
  Tell me your mood
  \IfSolutionPrintT{\par\blank[width=4.8\linewidth,linespread=1.5]{} }
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Is there any conditional similar to \IfSolutionPrintTF that works outside of an exercise? E.g. something like "\IfSolutionPrintF{\pagenumbering{gobble}}" right after \begin{document}...

Comment: @TeoFed89 I can't remember and have to check, but doesn't `\IfSolutionPrint(TF)` work outside?

Comment: I always get an error message when I try that precise command within \AtBeginDocument. I patched this by creating a boolean switch that, when true, sets "solution/print=true" AND does some other things. It would be curious though to understand why it didn't work on the first try... from what I read in the documentation I thought that \IfSolutionPrint(TF) only works within an exercise template.